# How to link shared library to another shared library

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface, g++, shared-libraries

I am trying to create shared library which is implementing JNI(Java Native Interface). My shared library is using another shared library which is named **libPosAPI.so**. But my shared library not correctly linking shared functions of `libPosAPI.so`.

In an implementation cpp, i am trying to use function `vatps::PosAPI::sendData()` of `libPosAPI.so`. Here is my build command:

`g++ -fPIC -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" -I. -shared -o libPosAPIJni.so main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni.cpp`

It compiles successfully. Even it does not ask to provide `libPosAPI.so` with linker. But when use output shared library(`libPosAPIJni.so`), it gives following error `undefined symbol: _ZN5vatps6PosAPI8sendDataB5cxx11Ev`. I also provided libPosAPI.so with `-L -l` options. The result is same.

Here is my header file. That is a result of `javac -h PosAPIJni.java`.

main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni */

#ifndef _Included_main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni
#define _Included_main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*
 * Class:     main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni
 * Method:    sendData
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni_sendData
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni.cpp

```
#include "main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni.h"
#include "PosAPI.h" // header file of libPosAPI.so
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline string jstring_to_string(JNIEnv* env, jstring string) {
    string value;
....
}

// IMPLEMENTATIONS
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_main_ubp_pos_PosAPIJni_sendData(JNIEnv* env,
        jclass cls) {
    string res_sendData = vatps::PosAPI::sendData(); // The PROBLEM IS HERE!!. trying to use function of libPosAPI.so. declared in PosAPI.h

    return string_to_jstring(env, res_sendData);
}
```

The output of `nm` command of two shared libraries:

`nm -D libPosAPI.so | grep sendData` :

```
000000000000c3e0 T sendData
000000000000a8dc T _ZN5vatps6PosAPI8sendDataEv
```

`nm -u libPosAPIJni.so | grep sendData`:

```
U _ZN5vatps6PosAPI8sendDataB5cxx11Ev
```

Please direct me right way :)

Comment: Building a shared library is almost like building an executable program. If the library depends on other libraries, you actually need to link with those other libraries (using the normal `-l`, lower-case L, option).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude . Of cource I provided link options: `-L. -lPosAPI`. But error was same. Also it confuses me. Why it does not give a compile time `undefined reference` error when I omit `-L -l `options?

Comment: On POSIX systems (like Linux) order matters when giving arguments to GCC. When linking with libraries, put the libraries *last*, or at least after your source or object files.

Comment: Comparing the lists of symbols for `sendData` it seems to me as if there is a mismatch in the C++ prototype. Your library needs `_ZN5vatps6PosAPI8sendDataB5cxx11Ev` but the other library provides `_ZN5vatps6PosAPI8sendDataEv`. There is an extra part `B5cxx11` but I have no idea where is comes from, maybe a compilation issue?

Comment: @thebusybee thank you for notice that. That is the main issue what I need to understand. But I also have no idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's decode your symbol:

```
$ c++filt _ZN5vatps6PosAPI8sendDataB5cxx11Ev
vatps::PosAPI::sendData[abi:cxx11]()
```

So, your code expects `sendData` with `std::string` with C++11 ABI, whereas `libPosAPI.so` provides `sendData` with pre-C++11 ABI `std::string`.

`abi:cxx11` hints to [GCC5 and the C++11 ABI](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/):

> Users that depend on third-party libraries or plugin interfaces that still use the old ABI can build their code with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and everything should work fine. In most cases, it will be obvious when this flag is needed because of errors from the linker complaining about unresolved symbols involving `__cxx11`.